# INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR on PayPal order pay

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

**Question updated - more details added.**
I get a 500 (INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR) error from PayPal when I try to pay for an order.

I get ok from create order, and get the orderID - order status CREATED. 
The order is approved by buyer - successfully  and order status become APPROVED.

Order created by https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders

Approved using paypal https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js

```
{
"id": "53T50821FM697283T",
"gross_total_amount": {
    "value": "26.66",
    "currency": "ILS"
},
"purchase_units": [
    {
        "reference_id": "20180318-64466",
        "amount": {
            "currency": "ILS",
            "total": "26.66"
        },
        "payee": {
            "email": "d0535318380-classeeks@gmail.com"
        },
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "Meeting",
                "sku": "20180318-64466",
                "description": "Meeting 1/26/2018 1:00 AM-1/26/2018 2:20 AM. aaaaa",
                "price": "26.66",
                "currency": "ILS",
                "quantity": 1
            }
        ],
        "shipping_address": {
            "recipient_name": "Andrey Dyachenko",
            "line1": "ישראליס 5 דירה 4",
            "city": "תל-אביב",
            "country_code": "IL",
            "postal_code": "61014",
            "state": "",
            "type": "HOME_OR_WORK"
        },
        "partner_fee_details": {
            "receiver": {
                "email": "d0535318380-reciver@gmail.com"
            },
            "amount": {
                "value": "12.66",
                "currency": "ILS"
            }
        }
    }
],
"payer_info": {
    "email": "d0535318380-buyer@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "Andrey",
    "last_name": "Dyachenko",
    "payer_id": "BZDA9RCZXKYQY",
    "country_code": "IL",
    "shipping_address": {
        "recipient_name": "Andrey Dyachenko",
        "line1": "ישראליס 5 דירה 4",
        "city": "תל-אביב",
        "country_code": "IL",
        "postal_code": "61014",
        "state": "",
        "type": "HOME_OR_WORK"
    }
},
"metadata": {
    "supplementary_data": [
        {
            "name": "risk_correlation_id",
            "value": "53T50821FM697283T"
        },
        {
            "name": "buyer_ipaddress",
            "value": "109.65.134.129"
        },
        {
            "name": "external_channel",
            "value": "WEB"
        }
    ]
},
"redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "https://classeeks.com/order/details/70368c93-90db-4a8e-bd82-6d611acc2d17",
    "cancel_url": "https://classeeks.com/order/details/70368c93-90db-4a8e-bd82-6d611acc2d17"
},
"create_time": "2018-03-18T19:49:11Z",
"links": [
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/53T50821FM697283T",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET"
    },
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/53T50821FM697283T/capture",
        "rel": "capture",
        "method": "POST"
    }
],
"status": "APPROVED"
```

}

Next step pay with https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/checkout/orders/53T50821FM697283T/pay

```
{   "disbursement_mode":"DELAYED"  }
```

Response

```
{
"name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
"message": "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.",
"information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
"debug_id": "be0c6976ab17a"
```

}

Based https://demo.paypal.com/us/demo/go?page=cart

Comment: What is the JSON body you have sent?

Comment: there is too little information in the error message. Try to debug which request parameter causes this error

Comment: Question edited. More info was added!

Comment: I'm not sure if the error is not caused by the "payee" and "partner_fee_details.receiver". I don't understand exactly who is who? Is payee the one that receive the money or the one that takes only a percent (commission) from transaction?

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the order successfully, then you can either capture the order directly or create the authorization which places the fund on hold and later you can capture the authorization. Check the [doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/orders/) for PayPal order APIs.

Comment: PP_MTS_hzhu: can you take a look again to this issue? Extra data was added to the question.